# How to check if every word in a cell is in another column - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to see if every word in a given cell is in a list in another column. For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGdsU.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language are you trying to write this in? Or are you using a gsheet formula .etc?

Comment: Gsheet formula, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a link to a sample spreadsheet with *realistic* data entries. I see you mentioned in your comment to the solution offered by player0 that your actual match list would exceed the capabilities of JOIN. This was not included in your post, and I image many other factors haven't been included either (e.g., phrases instead of words, non-alpha characters in match list? etc.). The most efficient and effective way to receive a solution that actually works is to give us the entire picture. And the only way to be sure that happens is to share a link to a realistic spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A9:A10, ", "))=
 LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(1/(1/REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A9:A10, ", "), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A5, "^$"))))),,9^9)), " ", )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that the list column will exceed the join char limit, at scale. Any idea that doesn't use join?

Comment: @snidsnid could be doable with helper columns where you could use simple COUNTIF formula.